# Why is message[i] returning an uninitialized value in this string?

Tags: c, loops, c-strings, fgets, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void vowel_check(char message[30], int i);

int main() {
    char message[30];
    
    while (fgets(message, 15, stdin) != NULL) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 30) {
            vowel_check(message, i);
            i++;
        }
        printf("%s\n", message);
    }
    
}

void vowel_check(char message[30], int i) {
    
    if (message[i] == 'a' 
    || message[i] == 'e' 
    || message[i] == 'i' 
    || message[i] == 'o' 
    || message[i] == 'u') {
        message[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
}
```

[the compile error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxkKt.png)

So it was my first time learning strings, and I want to make a program that gets rid of all the vowels in the program.

ex) white milk -> wht mlk

I think I'm not stuck in something massive and extremely challenging, I think I didn't get the hang of strings just yet.
Can anyone point out what part of my code I did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: 1. You used uninitialized element. Stop when you found the end of string `'\0'`. 2. Assigning `'\0'` won't slide the left part of the string and it will just terminate the string there.

Comment: @Lex Why is there while (fgets(message, 15, stdin) != NULL) { used the magic number 15 ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a character array with `30` elements

```
char message[30];
```

but in the call of `fgets` you are using the magic number `15` by an unknown reason

```
while (fgets(message, 15, stdin) != NULL) {
```

The user can enter a string that contains even much less than `15` symbols. In this case this while loop

```
while (i < 30) {
    vowel_check(message, i);
    i++;
}
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Also changing a vowel to the zero character

```
message[i] = '\0'
```

does not remove the element that contained a vowel from the string.

And this statement within the function

```
i++;
```

has no effect.

It seems you need to write a function that will remove vowels from a string.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how such a function can be written.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * remove_vowels( char *s )
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiou";

    char *src = s, *dsn = s;

    do
    {
        if ( *src == '\0'  || strchr( vowels, *src ) == NULL )
        {
            if ( dsn != src ) *dsn = *src;
            ++dsn;
        }
    } while ( *src++ );

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "white milk";

    printf( "%s -> ", s );
    puts( remove_vowels( s ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
white milk -> wht mlk
```

Your main function can look like

```
int main( void ) 
{
    char message[30];
    
    while ( fgets( message, sizeof( message ), stdin ) != NULL &&
            message[0] != '\n' ) 
    {
        printf( "%s", remove_vowels( message ) );
    }
}
```